# Expression for polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

I wonder if it is possible to find a closed form expression for following sequence:
\begin{equation*}
C_1=1
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
C_2=x^2+\frac 32
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
C_3=x^4+5x^2+2
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
C_4=x^6+11x^4+\frac {115}{8}x^2+\frac 58
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
C_5=x^8+20x^6+56x^4+32x^2+3
\end{equation*}
Is there any method using Wolfram Mathematica?
These are coefficients in perturbative solution of a following equation on $\tau$:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{y^4}\tau^4-\frac{2}{y^2}\tau^3-\left(\frac 1{y^4}
+x^2-1\right)\tau^2+\frac{2}{y^2}\tau-1=0
\end{equation*}
were $x>1$ and $y\gg1$

Comment: How did you generate the sequence?